# document type in IE10 and IE8 (pdfobject.js v1.2)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-10, pdfobject

I am using pdfobject.js to render PDF file in ADOBE PDF reader plugin in IE10.

In the source code, it is using

`targetNode.innerHTML = '<object    data="' +url +'" type="application/pdf" width="' +width +'" height="' +height +'"></object>';`

`return targetNode.getElementsByTagName("object")[0];`

which does not work in IE10..
so I changed it to

`targetNode.innerHTML = '<iframe data="' +url +'" type="application/pdf" width="' +width +'" height="' +height +'"></iframe >';`

`return targetNode.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];`

However, it automatically downloads the PDF file and the file is not displayed in the pdf reader plugin..
I tried to use

`<embed>`

but still doesn't work!

Comment: You haven't given us any idea what your capabilities are or what you can change?  Why not just change the code to look for either type you might get if you are set on supporting IE8.

Comment: Ok, now I know what it is causing this issue.. will update the description